# Swagger UI from Springfox 3.0 not showing the POST methods in UI

Tags: java, swagger-ui, openapi, springfox

I am using Springfox 3.0 with a simple REST controller. In Swagger UI, only GET methods are showing up, but not POST methods.

[image: swagger UI screen]

I am also struggling to get my context path in Swagger UI. Actually the context path is appending after the endpoint not before. So I placed everything in tomcat root folder without context.

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SwaggerRest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

```java
    @Bean
    public Docket api() { 
         return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                  .host("localhost:8080")
                  .select()                                  
                  .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("test.maventest")).paths(PathSelectors.ant("/**"))              
                        
                  .build();      

-------------
@Component
// make sure it runs after the default plugin springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.WebMvcBasePathAndHostnameTransformationFilter
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 1000)
public class CustomMvcPathHostFilter implements WebMvcSwaggerTransformationFilter {
  
    @Override
    public Swagger transform(SwaggerTransformationContext<HttpServletRequest> context) {
        Swagger swagger = context.getSpecification();
        context.request().ifPresent(servletRequest -> {
            UriComponents uriComponents = HostNameProvider.componentsFrom(servletRequest, swagger.getBasePath());

            swagger.host(uriComponents.getHost() + (uriComponents.getPort() > 0 ? ":" + uriComponents.getPort() : ""));

            // set Swagger base path
            String basePath = StringUtils.isEmpty(uriComponents.getPath()) ? "/" : uriComponents.getPath();
            swagger.basePath(basePath); 
            System.out.println("baseoath "+basePath);
            // rewrite paths to remove the leading base path from each endpoint
            final Map<String, Path> newPaths = swagger.getPaths().entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    entry -> entry.getKey().replaceAll("^" + basePath, ""), Map.Entry::getValue));
            swagger.setPaths(newPaths);
        });
        return swagger;
    }
  
//Not showing in swagger ui

@PostMapping("/saveInfo")
    public ResponseEntity <?>  saveinFo(@RequestBody Student student) throws Exception {
        
        System.out.println("Saving  studinfo Response at ==>444444444" );
        return new  ResponseEntity <List<Student>> (studservice.save(student),HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the springdoc instead of springfox. It worked for me.

```
org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.5.13
```

Comment: ok.Let me try, Thanks Santhos